# pass variable arguments from a file

Tags: c++, inputstream, variadic-functions

Im currently trying to read some values of a file, and pass them as va_arg but its been imposible

here's my code

```
File to read
6 465 441 466 442 467 443 
4 12 124 562 124
12 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 4 5 7 6 3
```

In the file the first number is related to the number of arguments that i will work with.
How can i read that file to work with this function?

```
    myFirstCube->AddCell( atoi(num_of_args), "args");
```

in this case I need to pass all the values depending on the first number but I cant find a solution.
 This is the AddCell method I need to use

```
void ObjectView::
AddCell( const unsigned int& size, ... )
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start( vl, size );
    std::vector< unsigned short > f( size );
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
        f[ i ] = ( unsigned short )( va_arg( vl, int ) );
    this->AddCell( f.begin( ), f.end( ) );
    va_end( vl );
}
```

Comment: Why not read all the values into `std::vector<int>` and pass the container to `AddCell`?

Comment: hi @JamesAdkison, actually i can't use vector because I specifically need to read this like i said using va_arg, I updated the question including the AddCell method I need to use

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of arguments you expect or is it truly an arbitrary number of arguments? I can think of 1 tedious/hacky solution if there is some practical limit...

Comment: Why does it have to be done this way? There is an `AddCell` function that takes a pair of iterators... Why not read everything into a `std::vector` and call that function?

Comment: Any reason putting AddCell into a loop won't work? Variable number of arguments also includes 1.

Comment: `AddCell` exhibits undefined behavior. "**[support.runtime]/3** The restrictions that ISO C places on the second parameter to the `va_start()` macro in header `<stdarg.h>` are different in this International Standard. The parameter `parmN` is the identifier of the rightmost parameter in the variable parameter list of the function definition (the one just before the ...). If the parameter `parmN` is **of a reference type**, ... the behavior is undefined." [Emphasis mine]